# Jackson binary serialization for custom class

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, apache-jena

I am trying to serialize my class using Jackson in Binary Format and struggling with it after trying a number of different alternatives. I was hoping someone can help.

My custom class looks like:

```
    package com.common;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.List
    import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
    import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
    import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
    import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;
    import org.apache.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
    import com.quick.RDFMain;
    import com.quick.exim.Importer;
    import com.quick.exim.SQEJSONToRDFImporter;
    import com.quick.trans.RDFFormulaToSPARQLTranslator;

    /**
     * A reasoning request, with the request representation based on RDF  standards.
     *
 * 
 */
public class RDFRequest{

    private SimpleSPARQLQuery query = null;
    // TODO: Would it make more sense for context to be a Model?
 //   private ContextWrapper context = null;
 //   private ConfigWrapper config = null;
    List<Statement> context = null;
    List<Statement>  config = null;

    public RDFRequest(SimpleSPARQLQuery query,List<Statement> context,List<Statement>  config) {
        this.query = query;
        this.context = context;
        this.config = config;
    }


    public RDFRequest(){

    }



    public RDFRequest(String queryPath, String driverPath, String vehiclePath) throws IOException {
        String absoluteQueryPath = RDFMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource(queryPath).getPath();
        Importer<ArrayNode, ?> importer = null;
        ArrayNode inputNode = null;
        RDFNode internalFrom = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(absoluteQueryPath);
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(is);
        RDFFormulaToSPARQLTranslator translator = new RDFFormulaToSPARQLTranslator();
        Model inputModel;
        RDFRequest request = null;

        // Import the query from json
        JsonNode formulaNode = node.get("formula");
        if (formulaNode != null) {
            importer = new SQEJSONToRDFImporter();
            inputNode = (ArrayNode) formulaNode;
        }
        if (importer != null && inputNode != null) {
            internalFrom = (RDFNode) importer.importFrom(inputNode);
            inputModel = internalFrom.getModel();
            query= translator.translate(inputModel);
        }

        // Load the context data
        Model contextData = FileManager.get().loadModel(driverPath, "N3");
        contextData = FileManager.get().readModel(contextData, vehiclePath, "N3");
        ExtendedIterator<Statement> statements = contextData.listStatements();
        context = statements.toList();
        return;
    }

    public SimpleSPARQLQuery getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(SimpleSPARQLQuery query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public List<Statement> getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(List<Statement> context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<Statement> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(List<Statement> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

}
```

Take 1

```
public void  sendMessageUsingJackson(RDFRequest message,String topic){
    System.out.println("Inside RDF Request For client "+this.clientID+ " Sending Message");
    System.out.println("Topic on which "+this.clientID+" is publishing is "+topic);
    this.messageProducer = getMessageProducer(topic);
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        byte[] jsonBytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(message);
        BytesMessage m = getSession().createBytesMessage();
        m.writeBytes(jsonBytes);
        this.messageProducer.send(m);
        this.messageProducer.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

When I execute this, it throws:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "uri": org.apache.jena.graph.Node#getURI(0 params) vs org.apache.jena.graph.Node#isURI(0 params) (through reference chain: com.nuance.nrf.common.RDFRequest["query"]->com.nuance.nrf.common.SimpleSPARQLQuery["variables"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:838)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:387)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:38)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase._findAndAddDynamic(AsArraySerializerBase.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:96)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:2233)
    at com.nuance.research.jms.JMSHook.sendMessageUsingJackson(JMSHook.java:334)
    at com.nuance.research.main.RILImpl.exchangeMessage(RILImpl.java:28)
    at com.nuance.research.main.RILTestClient.main(RILTestClient.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "uri": org.apache.jena.graph.Node#getURI(0 params) vs org.apache.jena.graph.Node#isURI(0 params)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getGetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getAccessor(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:283)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.removeIgnorableTypes(BeanSerializerFactory.java:678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanProperties(BeanSerializerFactory.java:557)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:373)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:268)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:213)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:873)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:833)
    ... 18 more
```

I have tried using other ways and have been struggling with it since two days now. I have to use an external library called Apache Jena and the error I am getting above is coming from methods related to classes in that package. Appreciate any help I can get or pointers to how to do a workaround. Eventually I want to convert the RDFRequest object to bytes and send it over JMS as ByteMessage. Happy to provide any clarification.

Thank you.